# Formula for colour a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need to fill a colour into the cells individually, if condition gets OK. Each cell with reference of different cell.

Means
if value of C1 is not between A1 & B1, C1 fills with red,

likewise,
if value of C2 is not between A2 & B2, C2 fills with red
if value of C3 is not between A3 & B3, C3 fills with red..

Comment: That's called conditional formatting.

Comment: Like JvdV said, use conditional formatting, select the column B, click conditional formatting, "add rule" => Formula: `=OR(B1<A1,B1>C1)` and then choose the background color to be red.

Answer (score 3):

In Excel, the **Conditional Formatting** can do this

1. Select the range of cells, and click **Home** > **Conditional Formatting** > **New Rule**.
2. Then in the **New Formatting Rule** dialog, select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** in the **Select a Rule Type** list, and type this formula `=OR(C1<A1,C1>B1)` into the **Format values where this formula is true** textbox, and click **Format** button to enable the **Format Cells** dialog, under **Fill** tab, and select one color you want to use for highlighting. See screen-print
3. Click **OK** > **OK**. Then the cells which are not in the number range have been highlighted

[image]